# Custom view rowformatter - how to make a hyperlink look like a button

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a list with a hyperlink field. I want to format the link to look like a button. I have tried a gazillion websites, gotten all kinds of CSS, but none of it seems to work.

I've tried two approaches - creating a button and creating an anchor hyperlink. The button type doesn't seem reasonable, as the "action" value set is limited to row list actions (open, edit, delete, etc.)

Here's a sample of what I've tried using an anchor hyperlink:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "Go to Client Data",
  "style": {
    "text-align": "center",
    "display": "inline-block",
    "padding": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-quickAction",
    "href": "[$ClientSiteURL]",
    "target": "_blank"
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please use the below JSON Formatting:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "[$ClientSiteURL]",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "Go to the Client Site URL",
      "style": {
        "background-color": "#E6E6FA",
        "color": "#2F4F4F",
        "width": "100%",
        "font-weight": "bold"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between JSON code I provided in my answer and your answer (except some extra styling)?

Answer (score 5):

Use JSON like below to create hyperlink with button:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "[$ClientSiteURL]",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "Go to Client Data",
      "style": {
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "width": "100%"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

Where `[$ClientSiteURL]` is an **internal name** of your column which stores hyperlink value in SharePoint list in this format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: I had tried this and it wasn't working - it turns out I had a missing bracket. Thanks for your help and providing me the PROPER coding!!!

Comment: How to set the value of [$ClientSiteURL] dynamically based on another column value?

Comment: `ClientSiteURL` is a internal name of another column only - which stores the hyperlink value in the list. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/). Check updated answer.